Using AWS API Gateway with Cognito as a frontend to on-premise private API resources accessible via AWS Site-to-Site VPN?
Locally, I have some api routes on a Kubernetes cluster, eg:
10.100.0.200/status
10.100.0.200/delete
10.100.0.200/create

In my AWS VPC, I have created public and private subnets with a virtual gateway connected to the private subnet and an internet gateway attached to the public subnet. My site-to-site VPN is attached to this virtual gateway. Therefore, I can create an EC2 instance in the public subnet and ssh to it:
ssh -A -i .ssh/ec2-deployer-key ec2-user@<public instance address>

I can then ssh to an EC2 instance in the private subnet and curl my local API routes:
[ec2-user@ip-10-250-2-99 ~]$ ssh ec2-user@10.250.1.99 -i ec2-deployer-key
[ec2-user@ip-10-250-1-99 ~]$ curl http://10.100.0.200/delete
{"message":"this is the delete route"}

With my local routes now available to AWS via the site-to-site VPN, I would like to use a HTTP API Gateway to expose those routes to the public internet. Furthermore, I need Cognito to:

Manage user authentication to the API.
Secure routes individually: so some users can use /delete, some can use /create, all can use /status and some can use all routes.
Store additional attributes about users to attach to the payload to my backend

eg a custom attribute in their Cognito user of role: engineer needs to be included in the payload / JWT sent to my on-premise API.



How can I achieve this?
So far, I think I need:

A VPC link between AWS HTTP API Gateway and my private subnet attached to the VPN gateway
cognito_user_groups in AWS Cognito, with roles attached to them that allow execution of the individual routes

eg a group create_user_group has an IAM role allowing the use of the /create endpoint.
users can be assigned to multiple groups


Custom attributes as required, but I'll need to write a custom JWT authoriser to bake this metadata into my JWT.

